# I'm trying to extract a string of data from a text file that has spaces.

Tags: batch-file

Here is my Code:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%1 IN (COAFN1T_N1E827682.BST) DO (
SET TempRecord=%%1
echo %TempRecord%
SET Strat=%TempRecord:~254,8%
SET VCNum=%TempRecord:~263,4%
goto EndWHile
)

:EndWhile
```

This is what it looks like when i run it. You can see when i echo TempRecord it is blank.

```
Z:\CLIENTS\COAF\NewUsed\BIN\BAT\test>(
SET TempRecord=201404   xxxxxxxx               xxxxxx               xxxx xxxxxxx
Rd.                                              xxxxx                TX xxxxx  
 xxx_x_V7   xxx_V2     N1E_V1     NUB_C_V8              2.39
              05/24/2014 4102014  VC01 03/31/2014
 echo
 SET Strat=~254,8
 SET VCNum=~263,4
 goto EndWHile
)
```

ECHO is on.

Answer (score 1):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

%n, where n is `0` to `9` refers to the argument number supplied to the procedure (eg. from the command-line) You must use a..z or A..Z for loop-control variables (there are a few other characters too, but only letters are documented) - and this is CaSe-SeNsItIvE,

so:

```dos
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN (COAFN1T_N1E827682.BST) DO (
SET TempRecord=%%a
echo !TempRecord!
SET Strat=!TempRecord:~254,8!
SET VCNum=!TempRecord:~263,4!
goto EndWHile
)

:EndWhile
```

should work for you - I haven't tested it.